springboot otlp telemetry turn off
I am using micrometer based otlp for enabling opentelemetry in springboot.
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'

I am looking for an option to turn opentelemetry off without removing these dependencies and/or other settings. I have tried all the below options in both configmaps as well as application.yaml but still end up with some traces being sent:
configmap changes:
OTEL_SDK_DISABLED: "true"
OTEL_JAVAAGENT_ENABLED: "false"
application.yaml chnges:
management:
tracing:
enabled: false
sampling:
probability: 0
But still getting this error in the logs. The jaeger collection is not up but i don't expect any traces to be sent from the server.
SEVERE: Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: jaeger-collector.default: Name does not resolve
Any other settings to be placed?
Thanks in advance!
SG

You can disable tracing (doesn't matter if you use Brave or OTel) by setting management.tracing.enabled to false:
management.tracing.enabled=false


Yes this is the application.properties version whereas i have specified the same in the application.yaml file with no impact

You might use an old version of Boot where this property were not present? Or something overrides this property?
